# PynamoDB Number of Items in batch_get

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb

I am using [Pynamodb](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) batch_get like this:

```
batchItems = MyModel.batch_get(id_list)
```

How do I know how many items in `batchItems`?

I wanna do something like if it's empty I would do something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this could be helpful for you, but I could get the items count using a for loop:

```py
item_count = 0
for item in MyModel.batch_get(id_list):
    item_count += 1

# Check the item_count
```

Comment: Throws this error ...TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: yeah @zretscen len() will throw error... maybe it's not a list?

Comment: Sorry, I answered your question assuming batchItems type as a list. I implemented a basic table and run batch_get method using Pynamodb. The first thing that came to my mind is using a for loop to decide items count. I'll update the answer.